# Series including the Gamma funtion

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form, gamma-function

In one of my calculation, I came across the series: $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{\Gamma(n+\alpha)}.$$
When $\alpha=1,$ this equals $e^x$ and when $\alpha=\frac{1}{2},$ this equals $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}erf(\sqrt{x})e^x+\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}.$ How can the general case be calculated in a closed form?

Comment: Use Wolfram Alpha `sum(x^n/Gamma(n+a), n=0..infinity)` and get the result in terms of the incomplete Gamma function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 1903, the Swedish mathematician [Gösta Mittag-Leffler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6sta_Mittag-Leffler) introduced the following [special function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpecialFunction.html):
$$
  E_\alpha(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{\Gamma(\alpha n+1)},
$$
where $z$ is a complex number, $\Gamma$ is the [gamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GammaFunction.html) and $\alpha \geq 0$. The [Mittag-Leffler function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Mittag-LefflerFunction.html) is a direct generalization of the [exponential function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentialFunction.html) to which it reduces for $\alpha = 1$.

In 1905, the Swedish mathematician [Anders Wiman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anders_Wiman) generalized Mittag-Leffler's function as the following:
$$
  E_{\alpha,\beta}(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{\Gamma(\alpha n+\beta)},
$$
where $\alpha, \beta > 0$, and everything else is the same as in the definition of $E_\alpha(z)$.

You can find more details about these function in this [survey article](https://arxiv.org/abs/0909.0230). I've also written a [related answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2753725/153012) yesterday.

---

*Update.* We can derive a simple form in your special case. The upper [incomplete gamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteGammaFunction.html) $\Gamma(a,z)$ and the lower incomplete gamma function $\gamma(a,z)$ is defined as the following:
$$
\Gamma(a,z) = \int_z^\infty t^{a-1}e^{-t}\,dt
$$
and
$$
\gamma(a,z) = \int_0^{z} t^{a-1}e^{-t}\,dt,
$$
for $a > 0, z \geq 0$. Note that $\Gamma(a,0) = \lim_{z\to\infty} \gamma(a,z) = \Gamma(a)$ and $\gamma(a,z) + \Gamma(a,z) = \Gamma(a)$.

Using the series expansion of $\Gamma(a,z)$ given in 8.7.3 [here](https://dlmf.nist.gov/8.7#E3), and the property given in 8.2.3 [here](https://dlmf.nist.gov/8.2#E3), and changing the variable $a \mapsto a-1$, then using the recurrence relation given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function#Properties), we find that

> $$
> \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{\Gamma(n+a)} = \frac{1}{\Gamma(a)}\left(e^z\,z^{1-a}\,\gamma(a,z) + 1\right).
> $$