# closed form of two series

Tags: closed-form

**Can the following series be written as a Mittag -Leffler function?**

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(z)^{(2n+1)}}{Γ((2n+1)\alpha+\alpha+1)}-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(z)^{(2n)}}{Γ(2n\alpha+\alpha+1)}$$
we have for one parameter Mittag-Leffler function :
$$cos_{\alpha}(t^{\alpha})=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^{k}\frac{t^{2\alpha k}}{Γ(2\alpha k+1)}$$
$$sin_{\alpha}(t^{\alpha})=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^{k}\frac{t^{(2k+1)\alpha}}{Γ(2\alpha k+\alpha+1)}$$
Can I write for the given series in terms of two parameters fractional trigonometric function ? for example in terms of $E_{\alpha,\alpha+1}$?

Answer (score 0):

We can simplify the expression as the following:
$$
z\cdot\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^{2n}}{\Gamma(2\alpha n+2\alpha+1)}-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^{2n}}{\Gamma(2\alpha n+\alpha+1)} = \\
z\cdot E_{2\alpha, 2\alpha+1}(z^2) - E_{2\alpha,\alpha+1}(z^2),
$$
where
$$
E_{\alpha,\beta}(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{\Gamma(\alpha n+\beta)}
$$
is the [generalized Mittag-Leffler's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler_function), with $z\in\mathbb{C}$ and $\alpha>0$.

You can find more details in my two related answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2753725/153012), and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2754591/153012).

Comment: I want to know Can I write  In the form of $E_{\alpha,\alpha+1}$?

Comment: @karen2 Why do you expect that form?